# C# File Stream Conflicts with Timer

Tags: c#, file, filestream, conflict, operations

I'm coding a program for recording security logs in c#. But there are several problems.

First i create a .txt file to record logs. With:

```
FileStream fs1 = File.Create("C:\\" + filename + ".txt");
fs1.Close();
```

Then, **in a loop** i write something in the txt file with:

```
TextWriter tsw1 = new StreamWriter(@"C:\\" + filename + ".txt", true);
//Writing text to the file.
tsw1.WriteLine(curLogs + " \n");
//Close the file.
tsw1.Close();
```

After that, I set a timer in c# and every -for example- 10 mins i want to reset log file.

```
    Timer timer = new Timer();
    timer.Tick += new EventHandler(ik.timer_Tick);   // Everytime timer ticks, timer_Tick will be called
    timer.Interval = (delay);                        // Timer will tick every 10 mins e.g
    timer.Enabled = true;                            // Enable the timer
    timer.Start();                                   // Start the timer
```

In the timer_tick handler, i want to delete the old log file, and create a new one with the same name, and continue recording logs. With:

```
void timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //FileStream fs = File.Delete("C:\\" + filename + ".txt");
    File.Delete("C:\\" + filename + ".txt");
    FileStream fs2 = File.Create("C:\\" + filename + ".txt");
    fs2.Close();
}
```

Syntactically there is no problem in the first iteration it's working perfectly but the problem is, after the first iteration of the timer, log.txt file becomes empty. Filestream can not write anything in it. I think there is a conflict between filestreams and streamwriter can you see any point that i couldnt see.

Thanks for reading, thanks in advance.

Comment: `FileStream`s and `TextWriter`s handle unmanaged resources and therefore implement `IDisposable`. Look into the `using` statement and how you should wrap these with it.

Comment: There are a lot of things wrong with this code.  The ultimate one is that you have to be quick.  If the program goes dormant for 10 minutes then you never have anything to look at.  Consider NLog for a better way to implement file logging.

Comment: I set delay 10 mins just to debug. Of course i will set it like 10 days after i solve this problem. But first i had to see is there anything wrong in this code.

Comment: I would recommend switching to something like Nlog or log4net. You can do what you want or much more. For example you could have a rolling log file that drops the oldest entries when the log gets over a size you set.

Comment: I have deleted my answer so people will not think this is a answered question that was not accepted, I hope you figure it out.